# AJAX not posting or receiving apparently

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I tell you what, getting AJAX to work is one pain in the wazoo!  It took me ages to get a simple string to pass and then I got a json array working and felt good, now I've tried to make a little adjustment and broke the whole thing again.  Why is following giving an ajax error and how can I get under the hood to see what's going on?

jQuery:

```
        $('#upload_form option[value="addnew"]').click(function(){

              // Show modal window
              $('#add-new').modal('show');

              // Get the class
              var Classofentry = $(this).attr("class");
              //console.log(Classofentry);


              $('#add-new-submit').on('click', function(){                


                  // Get new option from text field
                  var value = $('#add-new-text').val();
                  console.log(value);

                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>main/change_options",
                        data: {new_option: value, new_option_class: Classofentry},
                        //dataType: "html",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: errorHandler,
                        success: success
                      });

                  function success(data)
                  {

                    if (data[1]) // Only add new entry if unique
                    {
                        // Add new entry
                        //$('#animal_species').append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>");
                        $('#'+Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data[0] + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>");
                        //alert(data[0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Select the nonunique value by emptying it and appending
                        $('#'+Classofentry).empty("<option value=''selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>").append("<option value='" + data[0] + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data[0] + "</option>");
                        //alert(data[1]);
                    } 

                    alert(data[1]);                       
                    //alert('Success!');

                  }

                  function errorHandler()
                  {
                      //alert('Error with AJAX!');
                      alert(data[0]);
                  } 

                  $('#add-new-submit').unbind('click'); // This fixes the problem for multiple entries
                  $('#add-new').modal('toggle');                      

              });
        });
```

php:

```
public function change_options()
{
    # Receives and sends back user-entered new option and adds it to database

    # Get strings from ajax in view
    $value = $_POST['new_option'];
    $value_class = $_POST['new_option_class'];

    #Make array to send to model
    $value_array = array('Options' => $value);
    $unique = true; 
    echo json_encode(array($value, $unique));           
}
```

In the console I get: ReferenceError: data is not defined.  I've spent the last couple days working on logic to determine $unique and now the ajax won't work, even when I strip it back to it's bare bones.  What going on here?

Comment: throw a debugger on the line that it is complaining about data not being defined and work back from there

Comment: `success: success(data)`?

Comment: Why do you have a click function within a click function, just curious

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy: the nested click is thus far the only way I've gotten my add-new-option modal to work.  I know it's not advisable but I haven't got any unnested version to do it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687868/why-does-jquery-ajax-post-twice-here and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707553/modal-windows-and-binding-unbinding and help me out if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Th code I posted should've worked.  I found the issue and it wasn;t with ajax, it was with me passing the wrong thing to the model.  Here's the working code, with the logic to determine $unique:

(BTW, this solves the problem posed in [Form Validation in Codeigniter: using set_rules to check text input from a modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751413/form-validation-in-codeigniter-using-set-rules-to-check-text-input-from-a-modal) without using Form Validation):

```
public function change_options()
{
    # Receives and sends back user-entered new option and adds it to database

    # Get strings from ajax in view
    $value = $_POST['new_option'];
    $value_class = $_POST['new_option_class'];
    //print_r($value_class); die;

    #Make array to send to model
    $value_array = array('Options' => $value);

    $unique = true;

    $this->load->model('data_model');
    $elements = $this->data_model->get_options($value_class);

    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {
        if (preg_match("/$element/", $value, $matches)) 
        {               
            $unique = false;
            break;  
        } 
    }

    # Add new option to dropdown in database
    if ($unique) {$this->data_model->add_option($value_class, $value_array);}   

    //echo $value;

    echo json_encode(array($value, $unique));           
}
```